# Односвязаный список

Tags: c, алгоритм, односвязный-список

не могу понять где допустил ошибку при имплементации односвязного списка.

Для входящих данных:

```
2 -> количество итераций
3 1 2 0 (3 это сколько операций в данной итерации )
14 1 0 1 1 2 0 2 0 2 0 1 2 0 0
```

По заданию если код операции "0", нужно удалить первый елемент и выписать цифру.

Если код(k) операции больше 0, тогда нужно сделать новый узел с ключом k и вставить на k место.

Т.е для тех данных я должен получить такой ответ:

```
1
1 1 2 2 1 2
```

Ответ моей программы:

```
1
1 1 2 1 1 2
```

Мой код довольно тривиален:

Сама структура списка:

```
typedef struct list{
    int data;
    struct list * next;
}tList;



tList * init(int x)
{
    tList *lst = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    lst->data = x;
    lst->next = NULL;
    return(lst);
}
```

Добавленния элемента

```
void  push(int x, tList **head) {
    tList *tmp = (tList*) malloc(sizeof(tList));
    tmp->data = x;
    tmp->next = (*head);
    (*head) = tmp;

}
```

Добавленния на позицию Н:

```
void push_n_pos(int n, tList *head) {
    tList *tmp = NULL;

    int count = 0;

    while (count < n && head->next) {
        head = head->next;
        count++;
    }

    tmp = (tList*) malloc(sizeof(tList));

    tmp->data = n;
    if(head->next) {
        tmp->next = head->next;
    } else {
        tmp->next = NULL;
    }
    head->next = tmp;
}
```

Получения первого элемента:

```
int pop(tList **head) {
    tList  *prev = NULL;
    int val;

    prev = (*head);
    val = prev->data;
    (*head) = (*head)->next;
    free(prev);
    return val;
}
```

Реализация:

```
int main() {
    int operation;
    tList *head = NULL;
    cin >> operation;


    while (operation--) {
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        while (x--) {
            int z;
            cin >> z;
            if (z > 0) {
                if (z == 1) {
                    push(z, &head);
                } else
                    push_n_pos(z, head);
            } else if (z == 0) {
                cout << pop(&head) << " ";
            }
        }
            free(head);
            cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Пробовал чтобы добавлять самый первый элемент один раз, создавал для этого флаг. Но к сожалению ничего не получилось. **Не прошу решения задачи, только подсказки, где ошибка**

Comment: Можете подробней объяснить как вы получаете на второй итерации `1 1 2 2 1 2` вы добавляете 1 в начало, потом удаляете выписывая его, далее 2 единицы вставляете, потом двойку и получаете по идее `1 1 2` и потом удаляете 1 выписывая, потом вставляете 2 получая `1 2 2` и потом опять убираете `1` выписываете, и получаете `1 1 1`??

Comment: @ПавелЕриков это ответ который должен быть по условии задания. Задания "очередь к врачу". Вот что в задании о входящих данных: `The first line of input contains the number of test cases D. Each test case starts with number N of the events taking place in the clinic (1<=N<=1000).  Afterwards there are N natural numbers. A positive number is the number given by the receptionist to a new patient (not greater than the current number of patients in the queue plus 1), and number 0 means that the doctor calls a patient.`

Comment: Объясните простым языком, подробней как работает алгоритм

Comment: @ПавелЕриков постараюсь просто, у нас есть очередь к врачу, у каждого пациента есть свой номер. Первое число это к-лво наборов данных, дальше это количество данных в данном наборе. Если число равно нулю это значит что нужно удалить первый елемент списка и выписать на эеран, если число(n) больше 0 - нужно создать узел с ключем n и вставить на n место. Это дополнительное задание с универе. Все это нужно сделать на односвязаным списке.

Comment: XD я прошу вас рассказать поэтапно. В 1 комментарии я расписал, поэтапно как я понял алгоритм, но он получает `1 1 1` а не `1 1 2`. Вот я прошу вас так же расписать :) условие то я прочитал уже не раз

Comment: Я только сейчас заметил, что вы используете `cin` и `cout` хотя метка `c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как и ожидалось ошибка в вашей функции `push_n_pos`.

Например сейчас мы на `1 0 1 1 2` и все что вывелось, это `1`, а в данный момент список у вас `1 1` и вы хотите добавить `2`. Чтобы получить вывод `1 1 2` вам нужно вставить двойку таким образом `1 2 1` то есть, чтобы она находилась под индексом `n - 1 => 1`, то есть после первого элемента.

Так что вам в первом цикле, нужно при `n == 2`, чтобы `head` указывал на первый элемент, по этому нужно писать так:

```
while (count < n - 2 && head->next)
```

Я тестировал на `c++` (т.к. вы используете `cin` и `cout`) и выход у меня такой, как у вас в примере.

Comment: спасибо большое